# UPDATE old value using a conditional SET statement

Tags: mysql

I have an inventory table which contains all kinds of items like, lets say, 'milk', 'apple', 'tea'. These items have a quantity value. 
My second table is the table orderedItem. This table contains certain orders like 'apple'x2, 'apple'x3, 'milk'x5.

My query has to pick certain order rows (*in my example its an order featuring a certain amount of 'apples'*) from the orderedItem table, take the quantity of that order, and add/substract that quantity to/from the according row/value in the inventory table.

How can I fix this SQL query - I think the code written inside the bracelets 'quantity FROM orderedItem WHERE productname='apple'' might be broken:

```
query = mysql_query ("
    UPDATE inventory iv
    SET quantity = quantity - (quantity FROM orderedItem WHERE productname='apple')
    WHERE iv.productname = 'apple' ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the select:

```
UPDATE inventory iv
    SET quantity = quantity - (select quantity FROM orderedItem WHERE productname ='apple')
    WHERE iv.productname = 'apple' ;
```

This will not work if more than one row matches the condition (or even if none do).  So, you probably want:

```
UPDATE inventory iv
    SET quantity = quantity - coalesce((select sum(oi.quantity)
                                        from orderedItem oi
                                        where productname = oi.productname
                                       ), 0)
    WHERE iv.productname = 'apple' ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to fix my problem!